# Flask-OIDC redirect_uri value being overwritten somewhere?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, openid-connect

I've installed Flask-OIDC and am attempting to authenticate users with my company's service. I'm using a client_secrets.json file, which is being read, parsed and sent correctly for the client_id, client_secret, and other values. I am storing the redirect_uri variable in a line that looks like this:

```
"redirect_uris": ["https://example.com/_oid_response"],
```

When the request is sent to the authentication service, it's going out looking like this:

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Foidc_callback
```

Any ideas what's going on here? There's no "oidc_callback" string in any of my app's files, in any of the json, in any of the info I used to register with the authentication provider. Is it not set correctly, or being overwritten by Flask or the Flask-OIDC library somewhere?

Comment: Any luck getting this working?

Comment: @Atifm Nope, I ended up using a different library that was custom-written by a coworker for our particular OpenID connect stuff. Are you seeing the same issue?

Answer (score 8):

### The Fix

Use 
`OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://www.your-server.com/your_oidc_callback_uri'` inside configuration object (the same, where you keep `SECRET_KEY` or `OIDC_SCOPES`), e.g.:

```
app.config['OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI'] = 'https://www.your-server.com/your_oidc_callback_uri'
```

### Why it works

The default behavior of `Flask-OIDC` is that it uses `/_oidc_callback` endpoint on the application server (specified with `OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE`), without changing the schema or authority part of URL.

The problems may arise for example when someone exposes his application via reverse proxy over *https* (for instance using *nginx*). The flask application itself does not know, that it is exposed via https, thus it uses just plain http URL.

The source of this behavior is located in *Flask-OIDC*'s `__init__py` file, inside `_flow_for_request(self)` function.

```
def _flow_for_request(self):
    """
    Build a flow with the correct absolute callback URL for this request.
    :return:
    """
    flow = copy(self.flow)
    redirect_uri = current_app.config['OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI']
    if not redirect_uri:
        flow.redirect_uri = url_for('_oidc_callback', _external=True)
    else:
        flow.redirect_uri = redirect_uri
    return flow
```

Comment: Interestingly, although I did set `OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI`, I get another redirect after that to the http url (not the https url)

Comment: @MartinThoma are you sure that it's an issue on Flask's side (and not reverse proxy's)?

Comment: To fix that second redirect that goes to http instead of https, I used `flask-tallisman` that changes all redirects to https.

Comment: Did not work for me. See https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D54z00008KB6jpCAD/flaskoidc-does-not-work-as-expected-and-is-returning-redicrecturi-error?language=en_US

Comment: @HX_unbanned note that Flask-OIDC is terribly outdated, I would advocate against using it at all

Comment: @JackL. , I agree , but I still managed to get it working in my use case. So. Maybe I will migrate to Flask-Login .. but not now as other priorities are burning my butt ...

Answer (score 0):

Eric, I understand you have to manage OIDC_CALLBACK_ROUTE setting to route to the required URL (see here http://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Flask OIDC defaults redirect uri to /oidc_callback

Comment: What is "the required URL"?

Comment: @Eric  I am having the same exact issue. I set the OVERWRITE_REDIRECT_URI to my https load balancer on aws. This is my flow. I put the load balancer link on my URL. It redirects to the okta login page. Then I provide my credentials and then it goes to my flask app with a GET /oidc_callback which is returning a http:// with my load balancer URL. Anything I can do here ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon I am having the same issue while using it with AWS. were you able to solve it?

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon same here .. since some updates, the thing is broken.